# Fetching some data to ruby object periodically?

Tags: ruby, caching

I know it looks like a silly question , but how am I supposed to fetch some data to ruby object periodically ? or after number of tries ,

Lets say I have :

```
 @variable = SomeModel.all
```

and I don't wanna fetch the results all the time so I can do

```
 @variable ||= SomeModel.all
```

But how am I supposed to do that every periodic time without using something like memcache or 3rd party solution ? Any tricky way to do such a thing ?

Thanks .

Comment: have you looked into resque to see if it could do the job?

Comment: Not sure what you mean; you could always implement a simple time-based getter that returns the current value unless it needs a refresh. If you need something to occur *automatically* w/o modifying the class then Joseph is on the right track.

Comment: That was fast thank you, Joseph, isn't resque a wrapper for radis ? can't we do that through native ruby with any tricky code without the need to use any 3rd party gem  ? Dave thanks for the help i'm googling time-based getter thingy :)

Comment: Resque-scheduler would be your best shot in this case. Also, it is dead simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

untested:

```
Cache ={}
def fetch(key, ttl)
  obj, timestamp = Cache[key]
  now = Time.now
  if obj.nil? || now - timestamp > ttl
    obj = yield
    Cache[key]=[obj, now]
  end 
  obj
end
```

usage:

```
variable = fetch(:variable, 10.seconds) { SomeModel.all }
```

If `nil` is also a valid value, just use a default `:no_value_stored` as the default when reading from the cache and change the if block.

Sidenote: this *will likely* blow up on you if the keys are too many, as the hash grows indefinitely, so you should clean it up manually or use weak references.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that you are storing `@variable` somewhere where it can persist for many minutes (i.e. it can not be a controller instance variable, but it could be a variable of some module).

Next, keep a DateTime object representing the last time you updated the variable.  Every time you want to access the variable, check to see if the DateTime is older than 10 minutes.  If is older, then update the variable and the DateTime.

Comment: ya i'm not using rails at all, so i'm not using it inside controller. thanks for your help here , I think this is more than enough . Cheers